# How can I tally continuous sequences in a list?

Tags: sequence

I have a stream of data like this:

```
0001100111100000111111001110000001111111111000000111000111110000...
```

(I can represent them as a list, like in {0,0,0,1,1,...}, I guess that's easier to work with.)

Now I want to count how many sequences of two "1"s, three "1"s, etc there are (the zeros lengths are not important, they're just separators), to show them in a histogram. I have no problems doing this procedural, but functional programming remains difficult for me. While I don't mind pausing for a cup of coffee (there's 4.8 million data points), I guess in functional programming this will be orders of magnitude faster.
How do I do this with functional programming?

**Note**
"0011100" only counts as a sequence of length 3, the two sub-sequences of length 2 should not be taken into account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If* your data is in list form (conversion from string will swamp advantage), this should be quite a bit faster (5-50+X than existing answers, timings on the loungbook, so I'd expect 10+X faster for all on W/S):

```
tOnes = Module[{p = Append[Pick[Range@Length@#, #, 1], 0], sa},
    If[p === {0}, {},
     sa = SparseArray[Subtract[Rest@p, Most@p], Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"];
     Tally[Differences[Prepend[sa, 0]]]]] &;
```

Comparable in speed, and arguably prettier:

```
tOnes2 = With[{d = Join[{0}, #, {0}]}, 
    Tally[Differences@DeleteDuplicates@Pick[Accumulate@d, d, 0]]] &;
```

Comparison:

```
(* make some data & string/digit equivalents for string/Mr.W solutions *)
data = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 4000000];
strng = StringJoin[ToString /@ data];
mwdata = FromDigits[data];
ClearSystemCache[]

(* eldo *)
eldotim = 
  First@Timing[
    eldo = Tally@
       Select[StringLength /@ StringSplit[strng, "0"], # > 0 &];];

(* Mr. W *)
mwtim = First@
   Timing[mwr = 
      Tally[Length /@ Split[IntegerDigits@mwdata][[;; ;; 2]]];];

(* 2012rcampion *)
rctim = First@Timing[
    lengths = Cases[Split[data], l : {1, ___} :> Length[l]];
    tally = Tally[lengths];
    ];

(* kguler *)
kgtim = First@
   Timing[tally2 = Tally@StringLength@StringCases[strng, "1" ..];];

(* Me *)
me1tim = First@Timing[me = tOnes@data;];
me2tim = First@Timing[me2 = tOnes2@data;];

Transpose[{{"Mr.W", "eldo", "2012rcampion", "kguler", "Me1", "Me2"},
   {mwtim, eldotim, rctim, kgtim, me1tim, me2tim}}] // TableForm

(* Check *)
me == me2 == tally == eldo == tally2 == mwr
```

[image]

(* True *)

Comment: ... that "gut feeling"  again  :) ...+1

Answer (score 6):

```
strng = "0001100111100000111111001110000001111111111000000111000111110000";

tally = Tally@StringLength@StringSplit[strng, "0" ..]
tally2 = Tally@StringLength@StringCases[strng, "1" ..]
tally3 = Tally@StringCases[strng, s : "1" .. :> StringLength[s]]
```

all give

```
(* {{2, 1}, {4, 1}, {6, 1}, {3, 2}, {10, 1}, {5, 1}} *)
```

Comment: Very nice - the 2 points :)

Comment: Looks like yours is the fastest so far (0.7 s on 4M elements, vs. 1.5 s for me  and 2.3 s for eldo).

Comment: @2012rcampion, i don't expect it will stay on the 'fastest so far" list too long:)

Comment: @kguler: *Assuming* the OP has the data as a string (so no conversion overhead), this is about as fast as it can be done short of a chunk of C... +1

Comment: @kguler: Oops, I spoke to soon ;-)

Answer (score 3):

data = "0001100111100000111111001110000001111111111000000111000111110000";

```
Tally@Select[StringLength /@ StringSplit[data, "0"], # > 0 &]
```

{{2, 1}, {4, 1}, {6, 1}, {3, 2}, {10, 1}, {5, 1}}

Answer (score 3):

Generate 4M data points:

```
data = RandomInteger[1, 4000000];
```

`Split` into runs of identical elements, then find all sequences of `1`s and compute their `Length`s:

```
lengths = Cases[Split[data], l : {1 ..} :> Length[l]];
```

From here you can either `Tally` up all the lengths to use later:

```
Tally[lengths]//Sort
(* {{1, 499797}, {2, 249940}, {3, 124555}, {4, 62985}, {5, 31233}, {6, 
  15454}, {7, 7912}, {8, 3987}, {9, 1912}, {10, 969}, {11, 459}, {12, 
  238}, {13, 100}, {14, 59}, {15, 30}, {16, 6}, {17, 9}, {18, 6}, {19,
  1}, {20, 1}, {22, 2}} *)
```

... or make a `Histogram` directly:

```
Histogram[lengths, {1}, {"Log", "Count"}]
```

[image]

### Update

It's *slightly* faster (1.5 s vs 1.6 s) to use `{1, ___}` instead of `{1 ..}` as the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Integer input:

```
in = 0001100111100000111111001110000001111111111000000111000111110000;

Length /@ Split[IntegerDigits @ in][[;; ;; 2]]
```

> ```
> {2, 4, 6, 3, 10, 3, 5}
> ```

You can [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html) that if you want:

```
Tally @ %
```

> ```
> {{2, 1}, {4, 1}, {6, 1}, {3, 2}, {10, 1}, {5, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Short and sweet, +1