# Count the sequences in an array

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a short and easier way to count number of sequences in a list?

Let's say I have three lists:

`list1 = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`

`list2 = {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1}`

`list3 = {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0}`

There is one sub-list of 1's at `list1`, 2 sub-lists (two islands) of 1's at `list2` and 3 sub-lists of `1` at `list3`. So counting function should return to me 1 for `list1`, 2 for `list2` and 3 for `list3`. I am not interested in number of 1's in a sub-list.

I am using a previous *Mathematica* version, so I cannot use [`SequenceCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCount.html?q=SequenceCount) function. Thank you.

Comment: Do "blocks" consisting of a single 1 count?  In other words, should `{1,0,1,0}` return 0 or 2?

Comment: Yes, counts. That list should return 2.

Comment: Related: [(78976)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78976/121), [(83735)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83735/121)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
oneseqs[lst_] := Total @ Unitize @ Total[Split[lst], {2}]
```

Comment: I was going to say that it failed to count the `0` sequences, but then I noticed that is exactly what the op wanted.

Comment: @Leonid That's very elegant and fast. Thank you!

Comment: It counts for this `'{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`' two sequence.

Comment: @Algohi Yes, and this is what it should return in this case, if I understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 18):

This s/b quite quick (particularly with long lists):

```
MorphologicalEulerNumber[Image@{list}]
```

And this is even faster...

```
Length[With[{d = Differences@Prepend[list, 0]}, Pick[d, d, 1]]]
```

This seems quite quick:

```
f = Compile[{{z, _Integer, 1}}, Module[{c = True, cnt = 0},
   Do[
    If[c && x == 1, cnt++; c = False; Continue[]];
    If[x == 0, c = True];,
    {x, z}];
   cnt]];
```

Comment: wow, 2.5x faster than Michael's !

Comment: @SquareOne: LOL, I'd not even tested it, just recalled it from some work I did for the same kind of problem - counting "islands" of some value. IIRC, I came up with a really fast routine that beat this handily - looking for it now...

Comment: @SquareOne: Give the new one a spin...

Comment: I wanted to post `Differences` but you beat me to it.  A favorite method of mine for [related problems](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23623/121).

Answer (score 13):

Another method:

```
oneseqs[list_] := Count[Append[list, 0] - Prepend[list, 0], 1]
```

Technically, this counts the number of times the sequence shifts from 0 to 1, but that's effectively the same as the number of blocks of 1's.

**EDIT:**  Here are some performance figures for the four methods proposed thus far:

@Leonard Shifrin:

```
randlist = RandomInteger[1, 10^6];
Timing[Total@Unitize@Total[Split[randlist], {2}]]

(* {0.834908, 249707} *)
```

@Michael Seifert:

```
Timing[Count[Append[randlist, 0] - Prepend[randlist, 0], 1]]  

(* {0.077662, 249707} *)
```

@SquareOne:

```
Timing[StringJoin[ToString /@ randlist] // StringCount[#, "1" ..] &] 

(* {1.362467, 249707} *)
```

@algohi, appropriately modified:

```
count[list_, n_] := Total@Cases[Split[list], {n ..} :> 1] 
Timing[count[randlist, 1]]  

(* {0.304680, 249707} *)
```

Comment: Interestingly, I wanted to test the timing of the new (v10.1) function `SequenceCount` but for it seems it takes ... infinite time. Do you get the same behaviour ? : `randlist = RandomInteger[1, 10^4] ; SequenceCount[randlist, {1 ..}]`. (It works for 10^3).

Comment: @SquareOne Please read [(83325)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83325/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I missed that post. It's a shame ... And why aren't these functions coded at low-level ... I wonder what they would do without MSE contributors.

Comment: @SquareOne Directorial emphasis appears to be strongly in favor of *more* functionality over *good* functionality (fast and bug-free).  This is a shame.  Nevertheless there *are* improvements being made.  `SequencePosition` is much faster for verbatim (pattern-free) sequences thanks to the low-level-coded ``GroupTheory`Tools`SublistPosition`` which it uses in such cases.

Answer (score 11):

I am late to the party but here is my terse contribution:

```
f1 = Tr @ Split[#][[All, 1]] &
```

This is quite a bit faster than Leonid's `oneseqs`:

```
x = RandomInteger[1, 500000];

oneseqs[x] // RepeatedTiming
f1[x]      // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.2992, 125166}
>
> {0.0697, 125166}
> ```

For speed I propose:

```
f2 = Length@# - Tr@# & @ UnitStep @ Differences[# ~Append~ 0] &
```

This is somewhat faster than rasher/ciao's `Differences` implementation:

```
Length[With[{d = Differences@Prepend[x, 0]}, Pick[d, d, 1]]] // RepeatedTiming

f2[x] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00900, 125166}
>
> {0.00782, 125166}
> ```

#### Update

Seeking greater speed I considered working in the binary realm.  For that:

```
f3 = Tr @ IntegerDigits[BitShiftLeft@# ~BitXor~ #, 2]/2 &
```

The array must be converted to an integer first but even with that overhead it is faster:

```
x = RandomInteger[1, 1*^7];  (* larger array *)

f2[x]                 // RepeatedTiming

f3 @ FromDigits[x, 2] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.155, 2498958}
>
> {0.051, 2498958}
> ```

Comment: Haha. I was looking at this on my phone and saw someone was using the Tr function. I just knew it was MrWizard before I even got finished reading the answer.

Comment: Nice optimization you sly dog! +1

Comment: @ciao @Mr.Wizard It seems it's even a little bit faster if you use `Join` instead of  `Append` or `Prepend`.

Comment: @SquareOne On a packed integer array `Join` and and `Append` appear to perform similarly in 10.1.0.  What specific code are you using?

Comment: @ciao Thanks!  By the way which nickname would you prefer I use?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I replaced `#~Append~0` with `#~Join~{0}`. I tested 10^6, 10^7 random integers, `Join` is always 1-2% faster.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: call me whatever you'd like - I'm called lots of things ;-}

Answer (score 8):

After all these ingenious and interesting solutions only some simple remarks.

Jacob Akkerboom's solution shows that totally readable is a subjective concept. It took me some time before I really understood it (but it is very hot here today). In fact, his solution is an ingenious implementation of what could be done with `Fold` as well, thereby producing another (slow) solution for this problem:

```
clusterFu2[list_] := Module[{d = 0}, Fold[(If[#1 < #2, d++]; #2) &, 0, list]; d]
```

A timing:

```
randlist = RandomInteger[1, 5*10^6];
clusterFu[randlist] // Timing
clusterFu2[randlist] // Timing
(*
{1.98121, 1251006}
{7.37885, 1251006}
*)
```

So, to my surprise, Jacob's solution is about 3.5 times as fast as the construction with Fold.

But the Fold construction can be easily compiled:

```
clusterFu3 = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}}, Module[{last = 0, result = 0},
   Do[If[last < z, result++]; last = z, {z, list}]; result],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Now it is even faster than Mr.Wizard's intruiging function f2:

```
clusterFu[randlist] // Timing
clusterFu3[randlist] // Timing
f2[randlist] // Timing

(*
{1.96561, 1251006}
{0.0312002, 1251006}
{0.0936006, 1251006}
*)
```

Comment: I hope I didn't mislead you with my "totally readable" comment. It was meant as a joke, because the solution is so unconventional. I hope it was a nice puzzle :). I think the reason why it is faster than the `Fold` solution is quite subtle, but still it makes some sense to me. +1, especially for the `Compile` solution.

Comment: Hi @Jacob. I am always too serious ... But indeed, your solution is, at least for me, very unusual. Essentially, you have an If statement, of which you placed the second argument as part 0 of your uneveluated expression and the third argument as part 1, and then use the Part function for evaluating al these If's for the consecutive elements of list. Wonderful, deep, and as such a nice puzzle as well.

Comment: I can't compile to C (still!) but I'll trust your timings and give a +1.  I updated my answer to squeeze as much as possible from top-level *Mathematica* code and I think I got close to your `clusterFu3` based the ratio of timings.

Comment: I pushed it a bit further and  it is now 3X faster than `f2` so about the same as your code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard According to my tests, your `f3` is faster (10-20)%  than `clusterFu3 ` for 10^4-10^5 rand.int., slower by (5-10)% only for 10^6-10^7 rand., and for 10^8-10¨^9 it's 50-80% slower.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No need for C - in a quick test the new addition to my answer faster than f3...

Comment: @ciao My `f3` is nearly an order of magnitude faster than your `Compile` code on my machine on the test in my answer.  I can't imagine the CPU used makes *that* much difference.  Would you check your results again?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yeah, just did, and weirdly my Diff. based is faster than both on this machine - vagaries of the loungbook, I suppose (but since I throw them out every six to twelve months since cigar lounge smoke destroys them, new one inbound with a bit more modern specs - though nothing crazy - I won't blow clams on a box that's for fun and is going to die from smoke inhalation pretty quickly ... (

Answer (score 6):

for any number you can use:

```
count[list_, n_] := Total@Cases[Split[list], {n,n ..} :> 1]
count[list1, 1]
(*1*)
count[list1, 0]
(*2*)
```

Comment: `count[{1, 0, 1}, 0]` and `count[{1, 0, 1}, 1]` both return 0, which I don't think is the desired result.

Comment: Probable that is correct because no sequence of any number !

Comment: The OP clarified that sequences of a single 1 should count towards the total.

Comment: In this case replace `{n,n ..}` by `{n ..}`. it will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

Using `StringCount`:

```
StringJoin[ToString /@ list3] // StringCount[#, "1"..] &
```

> `3`

Answer (score 5):

Not very fast, but totally readable

```
clusterFu[list_] :=
 Module[
  {d = 0,
   bool = True},
  Unevaluated[
    Set[bool, True]@If[bool, bool = False; d++]
    ][[list]]; d
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
f[list_] := Plus @@@ ImageData@ HitMissTransform[Image@{list}, {{-1, 1}}, Padding -> 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but this is effectively the same strategy as Michael's:

```
Count[ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, list, {-1, 1}, 0], 1]
```

Comment: It works, and it is faster. Its run time does not seem to be sensitive to whether the input is packed or not, and is 85% that of Michael's in the packed case, and 60% otherwise. (I upvoted before I checked this, because I had faith... but I was not expecting the performance to be insensitive to packing.)

Comment: I am thankful that the faith was deserved in this case, @Oleksandr. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
b = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
c = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};
```

Using `SequenceCount` (new in 10.1)

```
SequenceCount[#, {1 ..}] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

{1, 2, 3}

Answer (score 2):

```
oneSeqs = Tr @* DeleteAdjacentDuplicates;

oneSeqs /@ {list1, list2, list3}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3}
> ```

```
WolframLanguageData["DeleteAdjacentDuplicates", "VersionIntroduced"]
```

> ```
> 13.1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SequenceSplit` and `Cases`:

```
l1 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
l2 = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
l3 = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};

f = Length@Cases[SequenceSplit[#, s : {1 ..} :> s], {1 ..}] &;

f /@ {l1, l2, l3}

(*{1, 2, 3}*)
```

Or using `SequenceSplit`, `Pick` and `ContainsOnly`:

```
f = Length@Pick[#, ContainsOnly[#, {1}] & /@ #] 
    &@SequenceSplit[#, s : {1 ..} :> s] &;

f /@ {l1, l2, l3}

(*{1, 2, 3}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `FindPeaks`:**

```
list1 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
list2 = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
list3 = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};

Length@*FindPeaks /@ {list1, list2, list3}
```

> {1, 2, 3}