# Count two or more equal consecutive elements in a list and create histogram

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

I have a list generated by:

```
list = RandomInteger[{1}, 100]
```

it contains only 0's and 1's

```
{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, \
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, \
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
```

I'm trying to create a histogram in the following way: I want to look for two or more consecutive 1's e.g. 1,1 or 1,1,1 and so on. In other words I want to count all sequences of two or more consecutive 1's.

I also want to extract the *positions* of the found sequences in the list.

I tried to approach it with PatternSequence based on the help entry e.g.:

```
list //. {x___, PatternSequence[1, 1], y___} -> {x, "mypatterns", y}
```

which seems ok for showing me where the patterns in the list are, but it does not count them or give me the positions :(

Looking for some inspiration :)

Comment: `Split` is you friend here :-)

Comment: Histogram: `Histogram[Length /@ Select[Split[list], First[#] == 1 &]]`.  Positions: `pos = Accumulate[Length /@ Split[list]]`.  Positions of the ones having 1s:  `Pick[pos, First/@Split[list], 1]`.

Comment: Thanks. Using Select and Split is actually very nice :), the histogram works for me here although it includes the patterns with only one 1. I don't understand the Positions code since I want e.g. the positions of the pattern with two 1's, three 1's in the original list, i.e. when does the pattern start and when does it end.

Comment: See this similar [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87406/19960) for the counting problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewritting, after author made clearer what was expected

```
   list = RandomInteger[{1}, 1000];
   PositionsOfNumeroUno = Flatten[Position[list, 1]];
   PositionOfSequencesOFNumeroUno =Table[{n, {ListOfPositions =Pick[Drop[PositionsOfNumeroUno, n - 1],Differences[PositionsOfNumeroUno, 1, n - 1], n - 1] - n + 1,ListOfPositions + n - 1} // Transpose}, {n, 2, 10, 1}]
```

This will give a list which will have as a first value how long is the sequences, and then the list of positions where this sequences occurs. Here I done it for up to lenght of 10 entries. To get how many entries there are of each length

```
HowLongAreSequences = {PositionOfSequencesOFNumeroUno[[All, 1]],   Map[Length[#] &, PositionOfSequencesOFNumeroUno[[All, 2]]]} //Transpose
```

Below I also plot results of the last command for a bit larger sample (10000 entries long). With blue I shown calculated value, and with orange the expected value (just from probability arguments, how many occuranges of such sequence I would expect in the sample)

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
list =
  {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
   0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
   1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
   1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};
```

Maximum length of consecutive 1's

```
max = Max @ Map[Length] @ SequenceCases[list, {1 ..}]
```

8

Counts of consecutive 1's with overlaps

```
ot = 
  Table[{n, SequenceCount[list, {Repeated[1, {n}]}, Overlaps -> True]}, {n, 2, max}]
```

{{2, 21}, {3, 9}, {4, 5}, {5, 4}, {6, 3}, {7, 2}, {8, 1}}

Counts of consecutive 1's without overlaps

```
of = 
 Table[{n, SequenceCount[list, {Repeated[1, {n}]}, Overlaps -> False]}, {n, 2, max}]
```

{{2, 15}, {3, 5}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}, {7, 1}, {8, 1}}

```
ListStepPlot[{ot, of}, Center,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Conscutive 1's", "Count"},
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Mesh -> Full, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Overlaps -> True", "Overlaps -> False"},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

To get the positions we replace `SequenceCount` with `SequencePosition`

```
Table[{n, SequencePosition[list, {Repeated[1, {n}]}, Overlaps -> False]}, {n, 2, max}]
```

returns

```
{{2, {{5, 6}, {16, 17}, {19, 20}, {28, 29}, {33, 34}, {37, 38}, {49, 50}, {60, 61}, {65, 66}, {75, 76}, {77, 78}, {79, 80}, {81, 82}, {87, 88}, {99, 100}}},
 {3, {{5, 7}, {65, 67}, {75, 77}, {78, 80}, {87, 89}}},
 {4, {{75, 78}, {79, 82}}},
 {5, {{75, 79}}},
 {6, {{75, 80}}},
 {7, {{75, 81}}},
 {8, {{75, 82}}}}
```